# magento 2 admin password update failed error 1064

Tags: mysql, magento2

I am new to magento. After installation of magento 2, I want to reset password for admin. I am using the following update query but it's giving me error message with code 1064.

Query:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('lawjasadmin',256),':law:1') WHERE username = 'jasmine';
```

Error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '),':law:1') FROM `admin_user` WHERE
```

Comment: Risking to sound a little stupid here, but why don't you just reset the password using the account management from admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento CLI to create new admin user with the following command, then you can go and change password of your original user.

```
<path_to_magento>/bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```